# Questions About Perl Filename Wildcard

Tags: perl, filenames, wildcard

I am using perl to address some text files. I want to use perl filename wild card to find all the useful files in a folder and address them one by one, but my there are spaces in the filename. Then I find the filename wildcard cannot address those filenames properly. Here is my code:

```
my $term = "Epley maneuver";
my @files = <rawdata/*$term*.csv>;
my $infiles;
foreach $infilename (@files) {
    if($infilename =~ m/(\d+)_.*\.csv/)
    {
        $infiles{$infilename} = $1;
        print $1."\n";
    }
}
```

The filename are like:

```
34_Epley maneuver_2012_4_6.csv
33_Epley maneuver_2012_1_3.csv
32_Epley maneuver_2011_10_12.csv
...
```

They are in a folder named "rawdata".

When I used this for terms that don't contain spaces, like "dizzy", it works well. But when the term contains space, it just stop working. I searched this on Google, but find little useful information.

What happens and how can I do this correctly?
Any help will be good. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`glob` operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) works like the command-line processor. If you write `<rawdata/*Epley maneuver*.csv>` it will look for files that match `rawdata/*Epley` or `maneuver*.csv`

You must put your glob expression in double-quotes:

```
my @files = <"rawdata/*$term*.csv">
```

Comment: @Denzel: I have added to my answer to explain

Comment: One more question is that when I am using code like "my @files = <"rawdata/*_$term_*.csv">", with "use strict", system will warn me  "Global symbol $term_ requires explicit package name". But "_" is just something in the filename, it is not part of the variant name. How can I prevent this and make it work?

Comment: You need to to ${term} to show perl the underscore isn't part of the variable name. so "rawdata/*_${term}_*.csv". Without that perl will assume that all allowed characters after the $-sign is part of the variable you want to use

Comment: Or escape the space, just like you need to escape `*`, `{`, `?`, etc.